# SQL Server memory reaches 100% & then stops responding?

Tags: sql-server, performance, memory-management, query-optimization, database-performance

First, I looked at SQL Server memory utilization using this query:

```
SELECT  
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Memory_used_by_Sqlserver_MB,  
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024) AS Locked_pages_used_by_Sqlserver_MB,  
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024) AS Total_VAS_in_MB,
process_physical_memory_low,  
process_virtual_memory_low  
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

This shows
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZTFL.png)

Most memory is consumed by Lock pages.
As I have understood, these lock pages in memory helps SQL perform better but in this case, as SQL reaches 100% memory utilisation wherein 90% memory used by these lock pages .

What shall I do remove lock in page config altogether?

Comment: It's *supposed* to lock pages in memory. What is supposed to happen is that the OS signals low memory so SQL Server removes some pages. To be honest you are best following [guidelines for max server memory](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/max-memory/)

Comment: Out-of-the-box [SQL Server configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options) typically has Max Server Memory setting of 2,147,483,647 megabytes. It's your first job as DBA to set that to a sane limit for your operating environment.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did that while I first encountered & understood about lock pages. Even after setting the max memory limit I am facing same issue.